# Javascript / Jquery call function

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I have an application where I use `InAppBrowser plugin`. In function `LoadStop` I overwrite a `button click event`.

```
function LoadStop(event) {      
    ref.executeScript({
        code : " $('i.icon-camera').click(function(event){ ButtonClick(); });"
    });

}

function ButtonClick() {
    alert("good");
}
```

`ButtonClick()` function don't get called.

### *****UPDATE*****

It's work:

```
ref.executeScript({
    code : " $('i.icon-camera').click(" + ButtonClick + ");"
});

function ButtonClick() {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert("joooasd");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
function LoadStop(event) {      
ref.executeScript({
    code : " $('i.icon-camera').click(function("+event+"){ ButtonClick(); });"
});

}

function ButtonClick() {
alert("good");
}
```

does it work?